# Escape all special characters in Presto

Tags: amazon-s3, utf-8, presto

Uploading data(CSV) to **S3 and then to Presto**. But due to problems with the data inside the files we have problems uploading from S3 to Presto.
The metadata are correctly formed but because of **problems in column B**, they are failing.

A;B;DATE

EPA;Ørsted Energy Sales & Distribution;2019-01-11 12:10:13

EPA;De MARIA GærfaPepeer A/S;           2019-02-12 12:10:13

EPA;Scan Convert A/S;                   2019-02-11 11:10:12

EPA;***Mega;                            2019-02-11 11:10:13

EPA;sAYSlö-SähAAdkö Oy;                 2019-02-11 11:11:11

We are adding replacement formulas in previous step (Informatica Cloud), to add \ and read the values correctly.
Is there a list of characters we should look for and add the \ ?

[image: Data in case text is not clear]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that according to standard if Your B column could contain separator then You should add quotation on that column. If there are quotations inside ( what for 99% can happen ) then You should add escape character before.

```
A;B;DATE
EPA;"company";01/01/2000
EPA;"Super \"company\""; 01/01/2000 
EPA,"\"dadad\" \;"; 01/01/2000
```

I had similar problem, it's quite easy to solve it with regular expression :

In Your scenario You can search for :

`(^EPA;)` and replace it with: `$1"`                      ==> `s/(^EPA;)/$1"/g`

`(;[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2})` and replace it with: `"$1`     ==> `s/\s*(;[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2})/"$1/g`

Final step would be global backslashes enrichment:

```
s/([^;"]|;")(")([^;\n])/$1\\$2$3/g
```

Please take a look on that: 
https://fullouterjoin.wordpress.com/2019/04/05/dealing-with-broken-csv-strings-with-missing-escape-characters-powercenter/